# Is the maximum of two weak subsolutions still a weak subsolution?

Tags: weak-derivatives, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

We say $u\in\operatorname{W}^{1,2}(\Omega)$ is the weak subsolution to the elliptic PDE
\begin{equation}\label{1}
-D_i(a_{ij}D_j u)=0\quad \text{in}\,\, \Omega\,,
\end{equation}
if there holds
$$\int_\Omega a_{ij}D_iuD_j\varphi\,{\operatorname  d}x\leq0\,,\quad\forall\,\varphi\in \operatorname{W}_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\,,\varphi\geq0.$$
Let $u_1,u_2$ be two weak subsolutions, set $v:=\max\{u_1,u_2\}.$ The question is $v$ still a weak subsolution?

**My attempt**

For any $\varphi\in {C}_0^{\infty}(\Omega),\varphi\geq0,$ there is
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_\Omega a_{ij}D_i v D_j\varphi\, {\operatorname  d} x&=\int_{\{u_1<u_2\}} a_{ij}D_iu_2 D_j\varphi \,{\operatorname  d} x+\int_{\{u_1\geq u_2\}} a_{ij}D_i u_1 D_j \varphi \,{\operatorname  d} x\\&=\int_{\Omega} a_{ij}D_i u_2D_j\varphi\cdot 1_{\{u_1<u_2\}}\, {\operatorname  d}x+ \int_{\Omega} a_{ij}D_i u_1D_j\varphi\cdot 1_{\{u_1\geq u_2\}}\, {\operatorname  d}x\,.
\end{aligned}$$
But I don’t know if $\varphi1_{\{u_1<u_2\}}\,,\varphi1_{\{u_1\geq u_2\}}\in \operatorname{W}_0^{1,2}(\Omega),$ since the character function may be so wired that the weak derivative does not exist.

I want to know is this proposition right? If right, how to prove it? Looking forward to your answer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$1_{u1<u2}$ is at least a measurable function. We can use continuous function to approach it, particularly, polynomial function. The Dominated convergence theorem thus guarantees the reasonableness .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method of approximation to prove $v$ is a subsolution. Note that $\Phi(x,y)=\max\{x,y\}=x+(y-x)^{+}$.  Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(t)=t^{+}=\begin{cases}
   t,\ t>0\\ 0,\ t\leq0
  \end{cases}$. Then $\Phi(x,y)=x+f(y-x)$.

My idea is approximating $f$ by convex $C^{1,1}$ functions $f_{\varepsilon}$,and showing that $v_{\varepsilon}:=\Phi_{\varepsilon}(u_{1},u_{2})=u_{1}+f_{\varepsilon}(u_{2}-u_{1}) $ is a weak subsolution, then let $\varepsilon\to 0$ to conclude the result.

For any $\varepsilon>0$, define  $ f_{\varepsilon}(t)=\begin{cases}
   \sqrt{t^{2}+\varepsilon^2}-\varepsilon,&\quad t>0\\
   0,&\quad t\leq 0
  \end{cases} $. It is easy to verify the following statements:

(1)$\ f_{\varepsilon}\in C^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}),\ 0\leq f'_{\varepsilon}\leq1$, and $f''_{\varepsilon}\ge0, a.e.\ in\ \mathbb{R}$;

(2) $f_{\varepsilon}\to f, f'_{\varepsilon}\to \chi_{\{t>0\}}, a.e. \ in\ \mathbb{R}$.

Set $\Phi_{\varepsilon}(x,y)=x+f_{\varepsilon}(y-x)$ and $v_{\varepsilon}=\Phi_{\varepsilon}(u_{1},u_{2})=u_{1}+f_{\varepsilon}(u_{2}-u_{1})\in H^{1}(\Omega)$, then $v_{\varepsilon}\to v$ and $Dv_{\varepsilon}\to Dv$ a.e. in $\Omega$. For any $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_{0}(\Omega)$ with $\varphi\ge0$, we have

\begin{align*}
   \int_{\Omega}a_{ij}D_{i}v_{\varepsilon}D_{j}\varphi&=\int_{\Omega}a_{ij}(\Phi_{\varepsilon,x}D_{i}u_{1}+\Phi_{\varepsilon,y}D_{i}u_{2})D_{j}\varphi\\
   &=\int_{\Omega}a_{ij}D_{i}u_{1}[D_{j}(\varphi\Phi_{\varepsilon,x})-\varphi(\Phi_{\varepsilon,xx}D_{j}u_{1}+\Phi_{\varepsilon,xy}D_{j}u_{2} )]\\
   &\quad +\int_{\Omega}a_{ij}D_{i}u_{2}[D_{j}(\varphi\Phi_{\varepsilon,y})-\varphi(\Phi_{\varepsilon,xy}D_{j}u_{1}+\Phi_{\varepsilon,yy}D_{j}u_{2} )]\\
  \end{align*}
Note that $\Phi_{\varepsilon,xx}=\Phi_{\varepsilon,yy}=f''_{\varepsilon}, \Phi_{\varepsilon,xy}=-f''_{\varepsilon}$. Since $u_{1},u_{2}$ are subsolutoins, and the nonnegative functions $\varphi\Phi_{\varepsilon,x},\varphi\Phi_{\varepsilon,y}\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$, then we have
\begin{align*}
   \int_{\Omega}a_{ij}D_{i}v_{\varepsilon}D_{j}\varphi&=\int_{\Omega}a_{ij}D_{i}u_{1}D_{j}(\varphi\Phi_{\varepsilon,x})+\int_{\Omega}a_{ij}D_{i}u_{2}D_{j}(\varphi\Phi_{\varepsilon,y})\\
   &\quad -\int_{\Omega}\varphi f''_{\varepsilon}a_{ij}D_{i}(u_{1}-u_{2})D_{j}(u_{1}-u_{2})\\
   &\leq 0
  \end{align*}

Let $\varepsilon\to 0$, from the Lebesgue domainated convergence theorem, we get $\displaystyle \int_{\Omega}a_{ij}D_{i}vD_{j}\varphi\leq 0$.

Hence, $v=\max\{u_{1},u_{2}\}$ is also a weak subsolution.